# SAS/Python: Find any spaces followed by a non-space string and replace space with a different value

Tags: python, replace, sas, find, space

I have data that looks like this:

```
1937   Paredes         3-1
1939   Suazo            2-0
1941   Fernandez     4-0
1944   Wilchez        2-1
…   
2017   Miralles       5-7
```

I want to read each line as a line of text. Find any instance of a space followed by a number, character, or any non-space symbol. Replace the space that precedes that number, character, or any non-space symbol with a "|" in the following manner:

```
1937  |Paredes        |3-1
1939  |Suazo           |2-0
1941  |Fernandez    |4-0
1944  |Wilchez       |2-1
...
2017  |Miralles       |5-7
```

Any idea how to this in SAS or Python?

Comment: Why?  Do you really need all of those other spaces you did not replace?  Why not just replace all groups of spaces with a `|`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use re.sub matching a space and assert a non whitespace char to the right:

```
import re

test_str = ("1937 Paredes 3-1\n\n"
            "1939 Suazo 2-0\n\n"
            "1941 Fernandez 4-0\n\n"
            "1944 Wilchez 2-1")

result = re.sub(r" (?=\S)", "|", test_str)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
1937|Paredes|3-1

1939|Suazo|2-0

1941|Fernandez|4-0

1944|Wilchez|2-1
```

Or find multiple whitespace chars without a newline

```
result = re.sub(r"[^\S\r\n]+(?=\S)", "|", test_str)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like butter on a toast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need to preserve the other spaces.  Why not just remove them all?

```
data _null_;
  infile 'have.txt' truncover;
  file 'want.txt' dsd dlm='|';
  input (var1-var3) (:$100.);
  put var1-var3;
run;
```

Results

```
1937|Paredes|3-1
1939|Suazo|2-0
1941|Fernandez|4-0
1944|Wilchez|2-1
2017|Miralles|5-7
```